# File imports in karma.conf.js file

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I am trying to set up tests for my Yeoman generated application. I have the files array in karma set up as the following:

`files: [
      // bower:js
      'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
      'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js',
      'bower_components/lodash/lodash.js',
      'bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
      'bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
      'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      // endbower
      'Project.Web/scripts/app/appModule.js',
      'Project.Web/scripts/components/ppFramework/ppFrameworkModule.js',
      'Project.Web/scripts/components/ppMenu/ppMenuModule.js',
      'Project.Web/scripts/components/ppPageContent/ppPageContentModule.js',
      'Project.Web/scripts/**/*.js',
      'Project.Web.Tests/mock/**/*.js',
      'Project.Web.Tests/spec/**/*.js'
    ],`

Notice how I have some hard coded JS file paths there. For some reason that I don't understand if I remove them and reply soley on the `Project.Web/scripts/**/*.js` then it does not find the files..

Any idea why? I believe my glob pattern is correct and the files get found when explicitly chosen

Here is the error:

[image]

Im my test I only have on import which is:

`beforeEach(module('ppApp'));`

I could include all the code from my angular modules etc but given it works when you have the hard coded references and works in the application I'm not sure that would provide much insight. I can update this if it is needed.

Comment: None of the hardcoded files is under PropertyPlot.Web. If what you mean is Project.Web, then I suspect it's finding them, but files are not loaded in the right order: modules are defined in some files, and used in others, and the module definitions must come before the module usages. If you have an error, then post it.

Comment: hanks, that was just a mistake, I was just changing the name of hte project to avoid publicizing what I was working on. If you could edit your comment that would be great. Thanks for your help. I have added the error in there now and some extra explaination.